# How to disable Ctrl+Shift+C in Firefox

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox

Firefox 84 (and earlier ...and later...): When copying from Firefox to the terminal, we tend to mistakenly use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy text (since that is how it is done in the terminal emulator. In Firefox, this very disruptivaly opens a developer console, which is not easily closed (i.e., you can't press the same key to close it). How can we disable that keybinding? I would not mind disabling the developer tools in their entirety if that is what solved this usability issue.

Comment: Does this help? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/

Comment: @ToDo Partial: these hotkeys work only once the page is fully loaded, not while loading or on a new tab, or in an edit dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we can anymore. Even through `about:config` you can set it to `false` but it still opens the developer console. There is 1 option that is guaranteed to work but it is not the nicest of methods: change the source and compile firefox. File ...

```
./devtools/startup/locales/en-US/key-shortcuts.properties
```

has an ...

```
inspector.commandkey=C
```

Change that to something else and [recompile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions) firefox.